# Is there a downside to creating a table for each import to save time upon search?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a web application with a very specific, albeit fairly simple set of requirements.

1. The user must be able to upload 100+ spreadsheets, each containing 40-200k rows.
2. The user must be able to perform near real-time searches (< 0.5 seconds) on *a specific spreadsheet import*.

Because the application does not need to search *all spreadsheets* a user has uploaded, but rather just a single spreadsheet designated beforehand, it seems that the most efficient way to do this would be to upload each spreadsheet as a database so that we only need to run through 200k hands at most as opposed to running through a database of potentially millions of rows by way of a pivot table, for example.  Am I thinking about this correctly?

My plan would be to make a database in the form of Username_SpreadsheetName and to simply import into that database and select from it when it comes time to search.

I know this works and it works well, but it seems really quick and dirty to me. Wondering if there is a more clean way to achieve a similar level of efficiency that I'm not considering.

Comment: do you need to keep the data after upload->search ?

Comment: @smith Yes the data needs to persist such that the user can login any time and click on a spreadsheet to search it.

Comment: We use such a system at work, we implemented SOLR (and ZooKeeper for HA).  But it does require another set of skills than PHP / MySQL.